# How do I disable the Mac OSX desktop switch fade

Tags: macos

I've toggled reduce motion, but this fade animation is still pretty bad.
Is there a way to just have it instantly switch?
I am on Big Sur.

Comment: Which fade are you talking about? When I switch desktops, I just get a slide.

Comment: If you use key commands, Ctrl + [number] instead of swiping, the slide is literally twice as fast. That's as good as it gets, I'm afraid. [Doesn't work for fullscreen apps… but then again, nothing works properly for fullscreen apps ;)

Comment: Theres two choices, slide (slow) and fade (less slow).
Yeah, I did notice the slide is faster while using numbers, but still annoying for my workflow.
I'm used to working on gnome linux, where it can be toggled off so it's instant.